# Storing multiple translations for retrieval

Tags: performance, sql, postgresql

I've designed a database schema to store multiple translations with the objective of it being easy to retrieve data and add more translations if ever needed in the future without needing to make any change at all.

[Here's a dbdiagram.io of the part of the database that's relevant to this post.](https://dbdiagram.io/d/5dd0b181edf08a25543e0336)

One of my bot commands take as input the hero name and grabs the user locale number id and pass it to the function parameters `i_hero_name` and `i_locale_id` respectively, and said function returns brief information about that hero if found.

Most of the tables (in this case the ones that aren't being joined in this function) are lookup tables to ensure referential integrity throughout the database.

The function I use is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Game.get_hero(i_hero_name TEXT, i_locale_id SMALLINT)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        name TEXT,
        story TEXT,
        grade SMALLINT,
        face_id TEXT,
        attribute_id SMALLINT,
        attribute TEXT,
        role_id SMALLINT,
        role TEXT,
        zodiac_id SMALLINT,
        zodiac TEXT,
        bra SMALLINT,
        "int" SMALLINT,
        fai SMALLINT,
        des SMALLINT,
        devotion_name TEXT,
        devotion_slot TEXT,
        devotion_value FLOAT,
        self_devotion_name TEXT,
        self_devotion_value FLOAT,
        exclusive_equipment_name TEXT
    )
AS
$$
#variable_conflict use_column -- TODO remake this, use better column naming.
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
        COALESCE(c.name, b.name),
        COALESCE(c.story, b.story),
        a.grade,
        a.face_id,
        d.attribute_id,
        d.attribute_name,
        e.role_id,
        e.role_name,
        f.zodiac_id,
        f.zodiac_name,
        a.bra,
        a.int,
        a.fai,
        a.des,
        g.name,
        a.devotion_slot,
        g.effect,
        h.name,
        h.effect,
        i.name
    FROM
        Game.Hero a

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Game.HeroTranslation
        WHERE locale_id = 2
    ) b ON a.hero_id = b.hero_id

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Game.HeroTranslation
        WHERE locale_id = i_locale_id
    ) c ON a.hero_id = c.hero_id

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT locale_id, attribute_id, attribute_name
        FROM Game.AttributeTranslation
        WHERE locale_id = i_locale_id
    ) d ON a.attribute_id = d.attribute_id

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT locale_id, role_id, role_name
        FROM Game.RoleTranslation
        WHERE locale_id = i_locale_id
    ) e ON a.role_id = e.role_id

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT locale_id, zodiac_id, zodiac_name
        FROM Game.ZodiacTranslation
        WHERE locale_id = i_locale_id
    ) f ON a.zodiac_id = f.zodiac_id

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT a.devotion_id, a.effect, b.name
        FROM Game.HeroDevotion a
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT stat_id, name
            FROM Game.StatTranslation
            WHERE locale_id = i_locale_id
        ) b ON a.stat_id = b.stat_id
    ) g ON a.devotion_id = g.devotion_id

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT a.devotion_id, a.effect, b.name
        FROM Game.HeroDevotion a
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT stat_id, name
            FROM Game.StatTranslation
            WHERE locale_id = i_locale_id
        ) b ON a.stat_id = b.stat_id
    ) h ON a.devotion_self_id = h.devotion_id  

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            a.hero_id,
            COALESCE(c.name, b.name) AS "name"

        FROM Game.HeroExclusive a

        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT exclusive_id, name
            FROM Game.HeroExclusiveTranslation
            WHERE locale_id = 2
        ) b ON a.exclusive_id = b.exclusive_id

        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT exclusive_id, name
            FROM Game.HeroExclusiveTranslation
            WHERE locale_id = i_locale_id
        ) c ON a.exclusive_id = c.exclusive_id
    ) i ON a.hero_id = i.hero_id

    WHERE (c.name IS NULL AND b.name ~* i_hero_name)
    OR (c.name ~* i_hero_name AND a.hero_id = c.hero_id);
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have two joins for the `HeroTranslation(s)` which one holds the default (in case there's no translated data) translation and one for the translation data of the user locale and then `COALESCE(translation, default_translation)`.

For Attribute, Role and Zodiac I don't need to do the same as above since there will always be a translation for them.

And then every hero has two kind of devotions, one which is for the entire team, denoted as `devotion_id` on the `Game.Hero` table and one that's only for the hero which is denoted as `devotion_self_id` on the same table.

Lastly, some heroes might or might not have an equipment, unlike Zodiac/Role/Attribute they might not be translated so I have to join both the default translations and the actual translations that the user is requesting.

I have no issues with the design, it works the way I want and it's performant with timings varying between 1ms to 20ms. I'm not sure whether to post the PostgreSQL planning due to the length so I'll go ahead and post the timing results instead:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM Game.get_hero('Yufine', 2::SMALLINT);
                                                  QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on get_hero  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=352) (actual time=18.196..18.197 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.061 ms
 Execution time: 18.254 ms
(3 rows)
```

Is there any improvement I can do to the query/function?